# Move entire column at the end of another column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a Macro that moves all rows in column "B" after the last cell with data in column "A".
One of the challenges is that the amount of data varies so I don't know how many rows there will be in column "B" (need to find through VBA code how many and cut all of them) and also I don't know the last row of column "A".

P:S - the data is ordered so there will be no empty cells until the last row of the column

[image: move columns]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick and dirty `Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Cut Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: Tried this and get a compilation error - "Expected: ="

Comment: The code should all be on one line.

Comment: Hi. Did this and worked great. now the problem is that when it gets to an empty column I get "Runtime Error 1004: This selection isn't valid..." - How can I check if there's any data in the column and skip if there isn't? - I assume this would fix the issue?

Comment: You can throw that line between these 2 lines `If Not IsEmpty(Range("B1")) Then` and `End If`  OR just add `If Not IsEmpty(Range("B1")) Then ` in front of the existing line so would be `If Not IsEmpty(Range("B1")) Then Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Cut Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The following Macro should do what you want assuming your data always starts in row 1, it will ignore if there is no data in the column

```
Sub mCutAndPaste()

Dim lRowA, lRowB As Long

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lRowA = ActiveCell.Row

Range("B1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
lRowB = ActiveCell.Row
If lRowB = 1 Then
Else
    Range("B1:B" & lRowB).Cut
    Range("A" & lRowA + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi. Did this and worked great. now the problem is that when it gets to an empty column I get "Runtime Error 1004: This selection isn't valid..." - How can I check if there's any data in the column and skip if there isn't? - I assume this would fix the issue?

Comment: Hi @Clay Maj, does the amended code solve the issue?

Comment: Allow me some hints as there are quite a lot of beginner traps included:  a) not declaring `lRowA` *explicitly* results in a Variant, not in a Long; b) not fully qualifying your Range references returns the currently active sheet, on the other side you overuse `Activate` and `Select` - c.f. [How to avoid ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba); c) there are more valid ways to get the last worksheet row than to reference it by an absolute row number of e.g. 1048576 (depends on versions). @Stuart